# программа, выделяющая опорные точки на лице человека. dlib ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-образов

Даров. Подскажите, нужно найти опорные точки на лице человека, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было с ними производить вычисления. Допустим, как на фото (см. фото). нашел, что можно использовать dlib, но вот незадача! я не могу никак его установить, уже все гайды посмотрел. пишу код в вижуал студио, установил cmake

```
pip install cmake
```

а так же установил через отдельные компоненты "средство CMake С++ для Windows".  после этого

```
pip install dlib
```

но появляется такая ошибка. так же пробовал и в pycharm и просто через консоль везде все одинаково. 
Не обязательно с dlib помогать, мне главное точки на лице найти. Спасибо!

python 3.7
win 10

Ошибка:

```
Installing collected packages: dlib
Running setup.py install for dlib: started
Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Derp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8nxioyi2\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Derp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8nxioyi2\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-us7gzfgo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
     cwd: C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\
Complete output (74 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine ╨▓╨╡╤А╤Б╨╕╨╕ 16.3.2+e481bbf88 ╨┤╨╗╤П .NET Framework
    (C) ╨Ъ╨╛╤А╨┐╨╛╤А╨░╤Ж╨╕╤П ╨Ь╨░╨╣╨║╤А╨╛╤Б╨╛╤Д╤В (Microsoft Corporation). ╨Т╤Б╨╡ ╨┐╤А╨░╨▓╨░ ╨╖╨░╤Й╨╕╤Й╨╡╨╜╤Л.

    ╨б╨▒╨╛╤А╨║╨░ ╨╜╨░╤З╨░╤В╨░ 29.11.2019 0:03:49.
    ╨Я╤А╨╛╨╡╨║╤В "C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.15.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" ╨▓ ╤Г╨╖╨╗╨╡ 1 (╤Ж╨╡╨╗╨╡╨▓╤Л╨╡ ╨╛╨▒╤К╨╡╨║╤В╤Л ╨┐╨╛ ╤Г╨╝╨╛╨╗╤З╨░╨╜╨╕╤О).
    C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.15.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(15,2): error MSB4019: ╨╕╨╝╨┐╨╛╤А╤В╨╕╤А╨╛╨▓╨░╨╜╨╜╤Л╨╣ ╨┐╤А╨╛╨╡╨║╤В "C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.15.3\ \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio \ 2019 \Community\ Common7 \ IDE \ VC \ VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" ╨╜╨╡ ╨╛╨▒╨╜╨░╤А╤Г╨╢╨╡╨╜. ╨Я╤А╨╛╨▓╨╡╤А╤М╤В╨╡ ╨┐╤Г╤В╤М ╨▓ ╨╛╨▒╤К╤П╨▓╨╗╨╡╨╜╨╕╨╕ <Import> ╨╕ ╨╜╨░╨╗╨╕╤З╨╕╨╡ ╤Д╨░╨╣╨╗╨░ ╨╜╨░ ╨┤╨╕╤Б╨║╨╡.
    ╨б╨▒╨╛╤А╨║╨░ ╨┐╤А╨╛╨╡╨║╤В╨░ "C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.15.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" ╨╖╨░╨▓╨╡╤А╤И╨╡╨╜╨░ (╤Ж╨╡╨╗╨╡╨▓╤Л╨╡ ╨╛╨▒╤К╨╡╨║╤В╤Л ╨┐╨╛ ╤Г╨╝╨╛╨╗╤З╨░╨╜╨╕╤О) ╤Б ╨╛╤И╨╕╨▒╨║╨╛╨╣.

    ╨Ю╤И╨╕╨▒╨║╨░ ╤Б╨▒╨╛╤А╨║╨╕.

    "C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.15.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (╤Ж╨╡╨╗╨╡╨▓╨╛╨╣ ╨╛╨▒╤К╨╡╨║╤В ╨┐╨╛ ╤Г╨╝╨╛╨╗╤З╨░╨╜╨╕╤О) (1) ->
      C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.15.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj(15,2): error MSB4019: ╨╕╨╝╨┐╨╛╤А╤В╨╕╤А╨╛╨▓╨░╨╜╨╜╤Л╨╣ ╨┐╤А╨╛╨╡╨║╤В "C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\CMakeFiles\3.15.3\ \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio \ 2019 \Community\ Common7 \ IDE \ VC \ VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" ╨╜╨╡ ╨╛╨▒╨╜╨░╤А╤Г╨╢╨╡╨╜. ╨Я╤А╨╛╨▓╨╡╤А╤М╤В╨╡ ╨┐╤Г╤В╤М ╨▓ ╨╛╨▒╤К╤П╨▓╨╗╨╡╨╜╨╕╨╕ <Import> ╨╕ ╨╜╨░╨╗╨╕╤З╨╕╨╡ ╤Д╨░╨╣╨╗╨░ ╨╜╨░ ╨┤╨╕╤Б╨║╨╡.

        ╨Я╤А╨╡╨┤╤Г╨┐╤А╨╡╨╢╨┤╨╡╨╜╨╕╨╣: 0
        ╨Ю╤И╨╕╨▒╨╛╨║: 1

    ╨Я╤А╨╛╤И╨╗╨╛ ╨▓╤А╨╡╨╝╨╡╨╜╨╕ 00:00:00.05


  Exit code: 1



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Derp/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-8nxioyi2/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8nxioyi2\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Derp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8nxioyi2\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Derp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8nxioyi2\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Derp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8nxioyi2\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Derp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8nxioyi2\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Derp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8nxioyi2\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Derp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-us7gzfgo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
----- Не удалось установить "dlib==19.18.0". -----
```

[image: Опорные точки]

Comment: *pip install cmake* - это круто! Я не знаю, поэтому спрашиваю: что, в винде и вправду *cmake* устанавыливается питоновским установщиком *pip* ?! Может быть вот здесь: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4_M8YTAPDg решается Ваша проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Нет возможности ответить в комментарии. Возможно это то, что тебе нужно: [проблема в MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478492/cmake-failed-to-run-msbuild-command-msbuild-exe).